# why lost Mysql connection pool after a period?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

My application using Mysql and Postgres at the same time, the web server is tomcat 7.0. After the application runs a period, like 15, 16 hours, it lost the mysql connection pool, and i get "Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object" error message in the log. So i need to start tomcat to restart the application to reconnect to Mysql connection pool again. I close each connection after it finishes query. This never happen on Postgres, just on Mysql, so... weird.

I use Singleton to connect to connection pool for Mysql and Postgres both. Below is the code for Mysql.

```
public class DB {
    private static DB database = new DB();
    private DataSource ds;

    private DB() {
        try {
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            ds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mobile_recharge");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DB getInstance() {
        return database;
    }

    public DataSource getDS() throws SQLException {
        return ds;
    }
}
```

one of the queries:

```
public boolean preSaveData(HashMap<String, String> mapXML, String date, String serialNum) {
    try {
        con = open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.writeLog(mapXML.get("terminalId"), mapXML.get("date_time"), "fails to insert order info into mysql: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    String table = new JudgeTidField().table(mapXML.get("tidField"));

    String query = "insert into " + table + " (Terminal_id, Yewu, Phone_number, Company, " + 
                   "Order_money, Balance, Actual_money, Order_record_date, Recharge_record_date, Province, Serial_number) values " +
                   "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    try {
        presta = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(query);
        presta.setString(1, mapXML.get("terminalId"));
        presta.setString(2, "recharge");
        presta.setString(3, mapXML.get("phoneNum"));
        presta.setString(4, mapXML.get("type"));
        presta.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(mapXML.get("price")));
        presta.setFloat(6, (float) 0.000);
        presta.setFloat(7, Float.parseFloat(mapXML.get("actualMoney")));
        presta.setString(8, date);
        presta.setString(9, date);
        presta.setString(10, mapXML.get("province"));
        presta.setString(11, serialNum);

        presta.executeUpdate();
        log.writeLog(mapXML.get("terminalId"), mapXML.get("date_time"), "success to insert order info into mysql");
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.getMessage();
        log.writeLog(mapXML.get("terminalId"), mapXML.get("date_time"), "fail to insert order info into mysql: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            presta.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

In the context.xml:

```
<Context  docBase="Mobile" path="/Mobile" reloadable="true">
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/mobile_recharge"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="500"
    maxIdle="5"
    maxWait="5000"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username="root"
    password="xxxxxxxx"
    url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3306/mobile_recharge?characterEncoding=utf8" />

  <Resource
    name="jdbc/pgsql"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="500"
    maxIdle="2"
    username="postgres"
    maxWait="5000"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    password="xxxxxxxx"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5555/runningacounts"/>
</Context>
```

In the web.xml:

```
<resource-ref> 
  <description>MysqlDB Connection</description> 
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/mobile_recharge</res-ref-name> 
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref> 
  <description>PGDB Connection</description> 
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/pgsql</res-ref-name> 
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall between your application server and your database server?

Comment: Assume you do good with connecting to the MySQL server, are you sure you have release the object reference after using the connection object? Otherwise the pool keep creating and reaches the maxActive, then failed to create one more. Furthermore, maxActive=500? You've tune MySQL to allow 500 active connections? The default value is 151.

Comment: Ken answer suggests you're reaching the maxActive limit: according to your code, Connection object "con" and PreparedStatement "presta" are member fields. Try to use local variables, and if JDK1.7's available try-with statement for each Closeable class.

Comment: (The reason I ask about firewalls is because connections can fall out of state if they're not used for a period of time)

Comment: @Alastair McCormack  there is no firewall between the application server and database server

Comment: @Will - any luck with any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL at least, I would recommend you research the connection pool validation and cleaning options, specifically `validationQuery`, `testWhileIdle`, `testOnBorrow`, `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis`, `removeAbandoned`, `removeAbandonedTimeout` etc - more details here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes

I have had similar problems with MySQL connections via JDBC in Tomcat, and sensible application of these properties resolved it so there was no need to bounce Tomcat after long idle periods.  Hope that helps.